# EF Core: how to run a SQL script whenever a new database connection is opened

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core

There is some connection-level code (`set collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'`) we need to run whenever a new database connection is opened. I see that in `DbContext`, there are `OnConfiguring` and `OnModelCreating` override methods available, but I don't see anything like an "OnConnectionOpened" method.

Is there any way to cleanly hook into whenever a new connection is created and run an initial SQL statement?

Comment: [Database interception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors#database-interception), in particular [DbConnectionInterceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.diagnostics.dbconnectioninterceptor?view=efcore-7.0)

Answer (score 0):

There are three types of interceptors. In your case DbConnectionInterceptor is the appropriate one. This is how you define a child class, notice the override events (**specially ConnectionOpened and ConnectionOpenedAsync**):

```
public class ConnectionInterceptor : DbConnectionInterceptor
{
    public override InterceptionResult ConnectionOpening(
        DbConnection connection,
        ConnectionEventData eventData,
        InterceptionResult result)
    {
        //Add your business logic       
        return result;
    }

    public override async ValueTask<InterceptionResult> ConnectionOpeningAsync(
        DbConnection connection,
        ConnectionEventData eventData,
        InterceptionResult result,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        //Add your business logic
        return result;
    }

    public override void ConnectionOpened(
        DbConnection connection,
        ConnectionEndEventData eventData)
    {
        //Add your business logic

    }

    public override async Task ConnectionOpenedAsync(
        DbConnection connection,
        ConnectionEndEventData eventData,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        //Add your business logic

    }
}
```

Register the interceptors with DBContext:

```
services.AddDbContext(options => options
  .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
  .AddInterceptors(new ConnectionInterceptor()));
```